# Why is my SharePoint script only working for me?

Tags: 2013, javascript, permissions, script

I have full control permission levels over my department's SharepPoint 2013 team site.

I have inserted a jquery in a script editor web part located in my list's New Form.

It works perfectly for me but I found out it doesn't work for anybody else. They can view any style changes I have inserted just not the one script. Does anybody know what the cause of this could be?

It is a script that hides/shows form fields based on another field's selection.

Comment: Have you referenced any file in your code from site assets or style library in your site? If Yes, please check it the file is checked in properly.

Comment: Yes. I have the jquery file in my style library. I took the link directly from the file and used it in my code.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. But you need to check-in the file after adding it to style library. Also make sure that other users has permissions to access this file.

Comment: I will follow up on this and get back to you Monday to let you know if this solves the issue! I really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Sure, you're welcome.

Comment: Hey! It worked! Turns out I didn't check in the jquery file. I guess I am still quite the newbie to make such a rookie mistake. Thank you SO much for helping me!!!! :)

Comment: It worked! Turns out I didn't check my jquery file in. Guess I am still a newbie to make such a rookie mistake. Thank you SO much for helping me!!!

Comment: Great. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have referenced any file in your code from site assets or style library in your site then you need to check-in and publish the file after adding it to style library.

Also make sure that other users has permissions to access this file.

Comment: Agree. A good setup for testing that kind of changes is to log in as a test user with minimum permissions. Often I use a IE10 or IE11 to verify the script as IE often fails where Chrome passes ( ES5 vs ES6 and so in)